# Python don't understand the logic behind this error UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'big' where it is not associated with a value

Tags: python

```
def main():
    
    print(big)
    big = "ags"

big = "Test"

main()
```

when this code is inserted the error message forms, I don't understand why because the global variable should cover it

On here though

```
def main():
    big = "ags"
    print(big)

big = "Test"

main()
```

This runs and displays ags

```
def main():
  
    print(big)

big = "Test"

main()
```

On here it would display Test
can someone please tell me how this works because i dont understand.

Comment: Before posting the question, [did you try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) even just to put `UnboundLocalError` [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=UnboundLocalError)?

Comment: Yes and I didnt understand it

Comment: What links did you find when you did that search? What did you read on those pages, and what confused you about it?

Comment: https://sentry.io/answers/unbound-local-error/
Does not talk about why this error occurs just how, there's no logic. Does python not have declarations or something

Comment: Please then just read the linked duplicate.

Comment: If you care, I tried it in Javascript and it worked fine
function  x() {
    
    console.log(test);
    test = 2
}
let test = 5

x();
this printed out what i expected it to be not an exception

Comment: JavaScript is an unrelated language with unrelated rules and semantics. There is absolutely no reason why anything working in JavaScript should tell you how it works in Python, or vice-versa.